# lodash group array of nested objects by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, grouping, lodash

I have the following data:

```
  var data = {
  "features": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "route_id": 522,
        "name": "the Mekong",
        "tour_id": 538
      }
    },{
      "properties": {
        "route_id": 522,
        "name": "Cambodia & the Mekong",
        "tour_id": 545
      }
    },{
      "properties": {
        "route_id": 521,
        "name": "Cambodia",
        "tour_id": 537
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to group values that have similar `"route_id"` into a nested array of objects; ultimately using lodash; so that the expected result will be as following:

```
var result = {
  "features": [
    {
      "properties": [{
        "route_id": 522,
        "name": "the Mekong",
        "tour_id": 538
        },{
        "route_id": 522,
        "name": "Cambodia & the Mekong",
        "tour_id": 545
      }]
    },{
      "properties": {
        "route_id": 521,
        "name": "Cambodia",
        "tour_id": 537
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using `_.group` but I don't know how to get the nested array under one object. Also note that there will be other keys along with the `"properties"` key but they're not relevant to the structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: yes it does group the duplicates and i implemented the solution in the referred question but i can't get the result as a nested array under the "properties" like i show in result how it should be like

Comment: @IbrahimMohammed I advice consistency with your `properties`, right now when there are multiple values, it is an array. If it there is only one, it is an object. You might want to consider array for `properties`

Comment: it's consistent, there's an array of features, each feature has a nested 'properties' object, this is a geojson specs but i eliminated some keys to make it simpilar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objects in the `features` collection contains one key, `properties`, then I strongly advice to normalize the structure, removing the `properties` key. Nevertheless, here's an implementation that you might be looking for.

```
var result = {
  features: _(data.features)
    // get all routes (get rid of properties key)
    .map('properties') 
    // group by route_id
    .groupBy('route_id') 
    // place properties key again
    .map(function(group) { return { properties: group };})
    // get grouped features
    .value()
};
```

Function references: [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map), [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy)

```js
var data = {
  "features": [{
    "properties": {
      "route_id": 522,
      "name": "the Mekong",
      "tour_id": 538
    }
  }, {
    "properties": {
      "route_id": 522,
      "name": "Cambodia & the Mekong",
      "tour_id": 545
    }
  }, {
    "properties": {
      "route_id": 521,
      "name": "Cambodia",
      "tour_id": 537
    }
  }]
};

var result = {
  features: _(data.features)
    // get all routes (get rid of properties key)
    .map('properties') 
    // group by route_id
    .groupBy('route_id') 
    // place properties key again
    .map(function(group) { return { properties: group };})
    // get grouped features
    .value()
};
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%; top:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what i needed, i appreciate your input with removing the properties key but there are other keys inside the collection.
i just removed them in my snippets to make it simpler.

Answer (score -3):

In jquery you can use $.extend(obj1,obj2);

Comment: i'm not using jquery, i need a Lodash solution or vanilla JS.